# The weaker axioms of group definition, can it be modified to the following?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the book "A First Course in Abstract Algebra", Edition 7, Fraleigh wrote that

> It is possible to give axioms for a group $\left<G,*\right>$ that seem at first glance to be weaker, namely:
>
> 1. The binary operation $*$ on $G$ is associative.
> 2. There exists a **left identity element** $e$ in $G$ such that $e*x = x$ for all $x \in G$.
> 3. For each $a \in G$ there exists a **left inverse** $a'$ in $G$ such that $a' * a = e$

My question is, keep #1 and #2 the same, but can #3 be modified into:

3. For each $a \in G$ there exists a **right inverse** $a'$ in $G$ such that $a * a' = e$

I try to prove it but seems not work, and here is my attempt:

First, I want to show the **right inverse** is also a **left inverse**

By #3, $\forall x\in G, \exists x'\in G, x*x'=e$, $ \Rightarrow x'*x*x'=x'*e$

$$ \exists x''\in G, x'*x''=e, \Rightarrow x'*x*x'*x''=x'*e*x''=x'*x'' \Rightarrow x'*x*e=e $$

How to proceed from here? or a counter example?

Comment: Besides the MSE questions cited, worth mentioning is the google search ["left-right system" + inverse + identity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22left-right+system%22+inverse+identity&filter=0).

Comment: Thank you very much @ancientmathematician

Comment: thank you very much @DaveL.Renfro